# Listing the html contents of a directory error

Tags: php, directory

So basically, I'm using PHP to read the contents of a directory (one that only contains html files) and then to create a list of links.

```
<?php

$dir="../zpress/pages/"; // Directory where files are stored

if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
{
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
{
?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename;
?></a></p>
<?php
}
closedir($dir_list);
}

?>
```

It works perfectly on the pages where it lists them, but when i open the link it goes to www.mywebsite.com/zpress/g.html, whereas it's supposed to go to www.mywebsite.com/zpress/pages/g.html

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to output the correct path as well in your `<a>` area. The user's browser has absolutely **NO** way to tell that you're listing the contents of some OTHER area of the site, and will build urls based on the address of the current page. So you need to have:

```
<p><a href="../zpress/pages/<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the output so it goes to the right directory:

```
<p><a href="pages/<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a></p>
```